# How to check if remote directory exists using Net::SSH::Perl

Tags: perl, ssh

Check to see if remote directory exists using Perl Net::SSH::Perl

I want to check if a directory exists on a report server using  the Net::SSH::Perl module.

This command works:

```
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -al /home/mydir");
```

But how can I do like:

```
if ( ! -e "/home/mydir/mydir_1" ) {
   mkdir "/home/mydir/mydir_1";
}
```

Any way to do this using this Perl module?

Comment: If you have `perl` on the remote end as well, just use `$ssh->cmd(qq{perl -wle 'exit -e shift' '$filename'})` and then look at the exit code

Answer (score 4):

The `-p` option for `mkdir` accomplishes what you want (no error if existing), so something like:

```
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("mkdir -p /home/mydir/mydir_1");
```